# camelCase Json Formatter as globally configured in Website not being honoured

Tags: json, vb.net, web

I've tried setting this in `Application_Start` of my website:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = New CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
```

But when I get the callback from my angular POST AJAX request (which goes to a WebMethod on my code-behind for that page) it returns the Json data in the original default format still (TitleCase).

One thing I noted in the app start is that after changing the contract resolver to `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`, it does indeed show as set to the camel case version, but the `DefaultContractResolver` still is there in the `Instance`.

Edit:
I'm guessing now this is because this is an Asp.Net *website* and not a *web application* that this doesn't work?

Output reveals that `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` does the conversion and read that this can't be accessed/changed. Anyone got any further light to shed on this?